# Sourcetree でコミットが出来ない

Tags: macos, git, sourcetree

Sourcetreeを使いファイルをコミットしようとしていますが、上手くできずに困っております。

#### 行った手順

Sourcetreeダウンロード後にローカルで新しいファイルを作り、ファイルをコミットしようとするとエラーが出てしまいます。

下記のようなエラー画面になります。

```
git: 'secrets' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

[image: こちらがエラー画面になります]

#### 試したこと

ホームディレクトリから下記のコマンドを実行しました。

```
brew install git-secrets　                           # コマンド

To reinstall 1.3.0, run `brew reinstall git-secrets　# コマンド後の表示
```

原因または解決策をご存知の方はいらしゃいましたら、ご教授をしていて頂ければ幸いです。

#### 環境

mac バージョン 10.15.6
SourceTree for Mac 4.0.2

Comment: 「ファイルを作り…エラーになります」までで、実際に行った手順を追記してみてください (質問は後からでも [edit] できます)。 / また、「試したこと」はコミットと直接関係が無いように見えますが、こちらはどのような経緯で実行したのでしょうか？

Comment: ご返事ありがとうございます。こちらはキータで見た記事を参考にして実行をしました。後々調べて見ましたが、今回解決したい問題と関係がないと気付きました。

Answer (score 1):

git-secretsを導入した場合、SourceTreeにも設定をいろいろ追加してやる必要があるようです。

(参考：[git-secretsをSourceTree (Macintosh)で使えるようにする手順](https://qiita.com/yamaryu0508/items/d959dc32442b08b8a0a4))

このようなツールのエラーの場合、エラーメッセージの「git 'secrets' is not a git command」で検索すると解決策が割と簡単にヒットすることがあります。多少長くてもエラーメッセージを検索するという方法を覚えておいて損はないと思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。こちらの記事を見まして、バージョンが古いので参考にならないかなと思っておりました。また、エラーメッセージで検索をする方法のご教授ありがとうございます。